# Socketio Get number of clients in room

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sockets, socket.io

I would like to ask for your help. I'm having a hard time with this function. It's supposed to check if the room has 0 or 1 clients inside, and then gives information back about whether another client can join the room or not (with a max of 2 users per room). 
I'm out of ideas about getting the number of clients in the room. I've checked the site and there were quite a few answers about this topic, working with earlier versions of socket.io. Now I've came to this function:

```
 io.in(room).clients((err, clients) => {
  console.log(clients.length);
});
```

It works and logs the right amount of clients inside the room but I have no idea how can I return that value to the outer function.

The `var user` consists of a whole JSON and I've been wondering if there is a quicker way to return the length of the array without digging into JSON.

There's the outer function:

```
function isRoomFree(room) {
    var user = io.in(room).clients((err, clients) => {
      console.log(clients.length);
    });
   //console.log(user);
    if(user < 2)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
  }
```

Is there any way to do that? I'm kinda new to the js, socketio and node.js

Comment: can you review the answer @yoozek ? leave a comment if it doesn't work for you, or accept it if it works

Answer (score 0):

Your function `isRoomFree(room)` is essentially synchronous, meaning that you call it and you wait for the result, however `io.in(room).clients` is asynchronous, meaning that you don't know when the result will arrive.

Mixing the 2 of them presents a challenge.

What you need to do is change your function to become async. I suggest you become familiar with the concept.

```
function isRoomFree(room, callback) {
    var user = io.in(room).clients((err, clients) => {
       if(clients < 2)
         callback(true);
      else
         callback(false);
    });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
isRoomFree(room, function(status) {
   if (status)
      console.log("free");
   else 
      console.log("not free");

   //continue your program logic inside the callback
});
```